# Check when a block is mined

Tags: web3js, transactions, blockchain, mining

Is it possible to know when a block is mined? Is there any timestamp or event/subscription?

Comment: Did you try [`web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders')`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-newblockheaders) ?

Comment: Yes, but I think you are notify when the block is added or created in the node, but no mined. I am running a testnet with two nodes(one miner and a peer), and first, I get a notification about block X, and then, one of my transactions is added to this block X.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. [See the manual](https://goethereumbook.org/block-subscribe/)

Comment: Is it possible using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use web3js filter to watch for the latest blocks. You can specify the filtering parameters and wait in a watch callback to be triggered on the event of the specified parameters matched.

The below example can work for the newest blocks.

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter({toBlock:'latest'});
filter.watch(function (error, result) {
     if(!error)
         console.log(result.blockNumber, " has been added in chain"); 
});
```

You can take a look here for further explanation [Webjs Filter API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter)